# Flutter InkWell widget not showing through a container's gradient and color

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, containers, gesturedetector

EDIT: I've tried wrapping the `Container` in a `Material` widget and moving the color property to the `Material` widget, but I'm placing a bunch of `ResourceCards` in a horizontal `ListView,` so the color from the `Material` widget seems to only fill the space around the `ResourceCard`.

I've created my own widget `ResourceCard` in Flutter. I wrapped it with a `GestureDetector` to detect taps, but I want to show some sort of feedback or effect to notify the user that it was tapped. I decided to replace the `GestureDetector` with an `InkWell` widget, but I don't see the splash effect through the container's linear-gradient and colour, so I just reverted it back to a `GestureDetector`. I've seen other posts with potential workarounds, but none of them work with a linear gradient and color. Here's what one of the `ResourceCard` widgets look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2txv.jpg. Here's the widget's code:

```
class ResourceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ResourceCard({
    @required this.colour,
    @required this.margin,
    @required this.cardText,
    this.onPress,
    @required this.cardCaption,
    @required this.paddingText,
  });

  final Color colour;
  final String cardText;
  final Function onPress;
  final EdgeInsets margin;
  final String cardCaption;
  final EdgeInsets paddingText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 75.0,
            height: 75.0,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                cardText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Circular STD',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            margin: margin,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [colour, Colors.blue],
              ),
              color: colour,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                  spreadRadius: 1.0,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: paddingText,
            child: Text(
              cardCaption,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white70,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                fontSize: 10.0,
                fontFamily: 'Circular STD',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You want the splash effect from the InkWell over the hole card, not only the rounded container with the gradient?

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html and check `Troubleshooting` section

Comment: @Manuel I wanted the InkWell splash to only show up on the card (the rounded container with a couple letters inside of it), not the text underneath. Essentially, I want it to act like a FlatButton.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a `Material` widget as parent of the `InkWell` and set its `color` to transparent. The `InkWell` must be set on the card only (in your example the `GestureDetector` is set on the whole column). To fit the exact shape, the `InkWell` gets the same `borderRadius` as your Card (Container)

Here is a solution of your build method. I placed the `InkWell` and `Materal` widget as parent of the `Center` widget

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 75.0,
        height: 75.0,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: onPress,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            splashColor: Colors.grey[500],
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                cardText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Circular STD',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ...
```

Comment: does not work on me if I include decoration on container

Comment: @Moralde-Sama wrap InkWell with an Ink widget, which has a decoration parameter

Answer (score 2):

Just set the background color you want on the `Material` class:

```
Material(
  color: Colors.grey.shade200, // background color
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    splashColor: Colors.grey.shade300, // splash color
    child: Container(
        // content
      ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the ink well to work well with decoration. You'll need to convert container to an ink widget. For example:

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Ink(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: parseGradient(getEventColor(Random().nextInt(2))))
```

The example above uses Ink in replacement to Container.